# select element over some divs without id and unique class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to change the text inside a div. My problem is, that this Div (its a output of a script where i cannot change the sourcecode) has no id or a unique class.

Now i dont know how i can select the div with the text "Move Section" div for jquery.

```
<div class="md-modal md-draggable md-show ui-draggable" id="md-editsection" style="max-width: 350px; z-index: 10002; top: 17.5px; left: 616.5px;">

    <div class="md-content">
       <div class="md-body" style="padding:0 30px 30px">
          <div class="md-modal-handle ui-draggable-handle" style="padding: 30px 30px 0px; cursor: move;">
             <div class="md-title" style="margin:0 0 12px;">Text</div>
          </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="is-boxes">
       <div class="is-box-12">
       <div style="text-align:center;font-size:16px">Move Section</div>
       </div>
    </div>...
```

How i can do that?

Comment: Is [`$("div:contains('Move Section')")`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) too obvious a starting point?

Comment: if i try that - $("div:contains(\'Move Section\')").text("new text'"); - that the whole layout will crashed - only the div with id "md-editscection" will be alife and contains the new text value!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$('.md-modal .is-boxes:nth-child(2)')`

Comment: If i try that "$(".md-modal .is-boxes:nth-child(1)").text("newtext");", the text will replace but the style informations will be lost - why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute equals selector to match `style` attribute value of element, as the value of `style` attribute for the element which should be matched is unique in `html` at Question.

```js
document.querySelector("div[style='text-align:center;font-size:16px']")
.textContent = 123;
```

```html
<div class="md-modal md-draggable md-show ui-draggable" id="md-editsection" style="max-width: 350px; z-index: 10002; top: 17.5px; left: 616.5px;">

  <div class="md-content">
    <div class="md-body" style="padding:0 30px 30px">
      <div class="md-modal-handle ui-draggable-handle" style="padding: 30px 30px 0px; cursor: move;">
        <div class="md-title" style="margin:0 0 12px;">Text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="is-boxes">
          <div class="is-box-12">
            <div style="text-align:center;font-size:16px">Move Section</div>
          </div>
        </div>...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find contain within div using `contains` selector.

```js
$('div:contains("Move Section")').text("new text").css('background-color', 'red'); // Do what you want to do with div.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="md-body" style="padding:0 30px 30px">
  <div class="md-modal-handle ui-draggable-handle" style="padding: 30px 30px 0px; cursor: move;">
    <div class="md-title" style="margin:0 0 12px;">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="is-boxes">
  <div class="is-box-12">
    <div style="text-align:center;font-size:16px">Move Section</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i try that - $("div:contains(\'Move Section\')").text("new text'"); - that the whole layout will crashed - only the div with id "md-editscection" will be alife and contains the new text value!?

Comment: Your html is not in correct format. Check your html. Some where div is not properly closed like your sample code. See update on  working snippet.

Comment: there are some more divs in and outside, maybe it crashed caused of them? in your snippet i missed the first div container "md-editsection"